# Induced representations and $(\varphi, \Gamma)$-modules

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $L$ be a finite Galois extension of $K$. Let $V$ be a $p$-adic representation of $G_L$ Let $D$ be the $(\varphi, \Gamma)$-module associated to $V$ by Fontaine's functor. Is there an easy way to describe the $(\varphi, \Gamma)$-module associated to $\operatorname{Ind}_{G_L}^{G_K} V$ in terms of $D$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $L/K$ is unramified, then the answer is exactly what Matt said. In the general case, you have to take into account the fact that $\Gamma_K$ is larger than $\Gamma_L$ and the construction is given in 2.2 of Ruochuan Liu's "Cohomology and Duality for (phi,Gamma)-modules over the Robba ring", see http://arxiv.org/abs/0711.4346

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I wanted to know. So basically, on the $(\varphi, \Gamma)$-module side, the construction is the "obvious" one. 

Answer (score 6):

I've always wondered this too.  I think that if $L$ over $K$ is unramified, then
we just take the $(\varphi,\Gamma)$-module for $V$, which is a $(\varphi,\Gamma)$-module over $\mathcal E_L$,
and regard it as a $(\varphi,\Gamma)$-module over $\mathcal E_K$ (which is a subfield
of $\mathcal E_L$).    (Probably you already knew this, assuming it is correct.)

In the ramified case, I'm not sure; hopefully Laurent Berger will see this and answer!

Comment: You have (or had in 2010) the gift of [prophecy](https://mathoverflow.net/a/49858).